# Why does my global Dictionary variable not properly set in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am using ASP Classic with VBScript, and I have been trying to create a Dictionary, populate it, then have it accessible globally. The way my page is set up, I have  a main Class for one of my Objects, that has multiple Display subs, and changing a "displaymode" hidden input causes the page to submit and reload a new page depending on which displaymode matches which display sub. It has worked well for everything so far, but I cannot figure out how to assign a Dictionary globally.

I have the Dictionary variable declared and set globally, then in one sub I call another sub to assign it. I can then use the Dictionary perfectly fine inside both subs, but when I try to use it in anything else outside those subs, it is empty. Here is an example:

```
Dim dict
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

DisplayObj

Sub DisplayObj()
   Dim example
   Set example = New exampleClass
   With example
      .Display
   End With
End Sub

Class exampleClass

   Public Sub Display()
      Select Case Request("Display Mode")
         Case "displayFull"
             DisplayFull
         Case "displaySingle"
             DisplaySingle
      End Select
   End Sub

   Public Sub DisplayFull()
      SetList()
      response.write ""& dict(0) &""
   End Sub

   Public Sub SetList()
      dict.Add 0, "hello"
   End Sub

   Public Sub DisplaySingle()
      response.write ""& dict(0) &""
   End Sub

End Class
```

So when the page is set to displayFull and the DisplayFull sub is called, the dict variable is set properly and displays "hello". I have a click event change the display mode to DisplaySingle, and when that loads it displays nothing, and says the dict variable is empty. How can I have the SetList sub set the Dictionary globally?

Comment: [Global. asa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525316(v=vs.90)) might help

Comment: You're not calling `SetList` in your `DisplaySigle` sub.

Comment: In my use case, basically DisplayFull shows a page full of messages for a specific person. The SetList method is used to make a Dictionary variable that is populated with every message for that person. I want to be able to be on the DisplayFull page (which sets the dict) and then click a single message which would call the DisplaySingle. SetList is just an SQL call that assigns each recordset item to a key and value in a Dictionary item.

Comment: Is Request("Display Mode") set? I don't think spaces will work for a form or querystring variable, try something like request("display_mode") and make sure ?display_mode=displayFull is in the querystring and try again.

Comment: I moved on to solve this issue in a different way, by avoiding the way I was struggling with in the question. You are correct that Display Mode would trigger an error, but I had actually named it DisplayMode and just made a spelling mistake in the question, not my program. Thank you all for your answers